# NHibernate 3.2 Mapping by convention (code) stored procedure

Tags: nhibernate, stored-procedures, mapping

How can I map a stored procedure using mapping by convention or 
mapping by code?

If it is not possible then how to map it by hbm and include it into 
configuration done by Mapping by convention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nhibernate 3.2 allows you to mix your mappings; that is you can use the mapping by code syntax and still have your old hbm.xml files.

See this [blog post](http://puredotnetcoder.blogspot.com/2011/07/mixed-mappings-with-hbm-and-mapping-by.html) to find out how.

For mapping a stored procedure then I recommend reading this [nhibernate.info Blog post](http://nhibernate.info/blog/2008/11/23/populating-entities-from-stored-procedures-with-nhibernate.html).