# Nhibernate mapping by code, how to use stored procedure?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, stored-procedures, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I use nhibernate 3.2 new feature mapping by code (and it works very well).

Ex :

```
[Serializable]
public class Profil
{
    public virtual int Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public virtual string Nom
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class ProfilMap : ClassMapping<Profil>
{
    public ProfilMap()
    {
        Id<int>(x => x.Id, map =>
        {
            map.Generator(NHibernate.Mapping.ByCode.Generators.Identity);
        });
        Property<string>(x => x.Nom);
    }
}
```

I'd like now to use stored procedure. With the old version of nhibernate, I use hbm.xml file like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <sql-query name="FillNouveautes">
    exec FillNouveautes :Idclient
  </sql-query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I used it this way :

```
    public void FillNouveautes(ISession session, int idClient)
    {
        var query = session.GetNamedQuery("FillNouveautes");
        query.SetInt32("Idclient", idClient);
        query.ExecuteUpdate();
    }
```

Is there any new syntax ? or shall use the old style ?

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution on [NHibernate 3.2 Mapping by convention (code) stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674643/nhibernate-3-2-mapping-by-convention-code-stored-procedure)

I have to mix hbm.xml and mapping by code. cf. http://puredotnetcoder.blogspot.com/2011/07/mixed-mappings-with-hbm-and-mapping-by.html

Now I have to test it

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you can't do this with FluentNHibernate. You can only use sprocs in the mappings if they directly associate with CRUD operations. What you *can* do however is use a hybrid FluentNHibernate configuration - Fluent Mappings *and* HBM files.

Comment: well it isn't really the official fluent nhibernate project but a new feature introduced by default in nhibernate 3.2 the mapping by code. (Btw it's the same syntax but not the same project)

Answer (score 2):

You should have a class for returning result set in my case it's GameActivity class

```
    public class GameActivity
    {
            public virtual DateTime Date { get; set; }
            public virtual string GameRoundId { get; set; }
            public virtual int GameProvider { get; set; }
            public virtual string GameName { get; set; }
            public virtual decimal RealBet { get; set; }
            public virtual decimal RealWin { get; set; }
            public virtual decimal BonusBet { get; set; }
            public virtual decimal BonusWin { get; set; }
            public virtual decimal BonusContribution { get; set; }
            public virtual int IsRoundCompleted { get; set; }
            public virtual int IsRoundCancelled { get; set; }
    }
```

Calling stored procedure "GetMemberGameActivity" to get the list

```
    var result = session.CreateSQLQuery("exec GetMemberGameActivity :mToken, :StartDate, :EndDate")
                        .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean())
                        .SetParameter("mToken", token)
                        .SetParameter("StartDate", startDate)
                        .SetParameter("EndDate", endDate)
                        .List().ToList();
```

Comment: I have learned a few things from looking at your code, but I don't see the instructions to inform `Transformers.AliasToBean()` how to convert results into a list of `GameActivity` objects.